# Mysql composite primary key

Tags: mysql, database-design, primary-key

I want to have a lookup table that links two of the same things to eachother. Say I have a 'Person' table and I want to lookup the relationship between two people. I'll have column one of the lookup be 'PersonId1' and column two be 'PersonId2' and the third column be 'Relationship'. Since the relationship goes both ways I don't need to have duplicate records with the PlayerId's switched. Is there any way to make mysql enforce uniqueness on PlayerId1 and PlayerId2 combinations regardless of which order they're in?

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No.

Longer answer: You could set up a trigger to swap the order of the two person ids if the second were smaller than the first, then write them, and use a composite key.

Even longer answer:  Not all interpersonal relationships are commutative (not all relationships go both ways).  What about the "Employee" or "Mother" relationships?   Even the "Friend" relationship, which is presumably peer-to-peer, might be better represented if you had separate rows saying A is B's Friend and B is A's Friend. So maybe you want a three-field composite key on this table.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to have a unique row record from `PersonID1` and `PersonID2` Column (regardless of the `Relationship` column)? If that so, you may use the Composite key (Multi column key).

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    PersonId1 INT,
    PersonId2 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (PersonId1, PersonId2)
)
```

Comment: Yes but what if PersonId1 is 9 and PersonId2 is 10 in one record but in another PersonId1 is 10 and personId2 9. That redefines the same relationship. I was wondering if there was a way to prevent that.

Comment: If ordering is your case, you can use a single field having `varchar` data type and then concatenate the `PersonId1` and `PersonId2`. And don't forget to make it as your primary key.

Comment: You must try and insert them in pairs or this won't work. `INSERT INTO relationship (PersonId1,PersonId2) VALUES (9,10),(10,9)` and the transaction will fail if one or more of those pairs conflicts.

Comment: @tadman, if it failed it only means there's something wrong with the record itself. And you can assure that all records are unique.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for composite pk. To prevent duplicate combinations, an extra varchar column with for example personid1+personid2 with a unique constraint on it may be a solution...

See also: [person data model example](http://www.erdiagrams.com/datamodel-person-idef1x.html)